# Why am I getting this error: "TimeoutError: [Errno 110] Connection timed out" using python code in Pycharm?

Tags: python

```
import smtplib

my_email = "*******@gmail.com"
password = "***********"

with smtplib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com") as connection:
    connection.starttls()
    connection.login(user=my_email, password=password)
    connection.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs="*******@yahoo.com",
                        msg="Subject:Hello\n\n This is the body of my email.")
```

In gmail the "less secure apps" feature was enabled. Conversely, in Yahoo, the "Generate App Password" feature was used and still got the same response for both instances.

Answer (score 1):

There can be many reasons for this error - typically it means something has gone wrong in setting up the smtplib connection and your email hasn't set.

To get a more descriptive and helpful error message, you need to enable debugging.

To do that add, add this line of code:

`connection.set_debuglevel(1)`

That will print out much more descriptive debugger messages to the console.

Answer (score 0):

try to set a port like 465 for gmail, `smptlib.SMTP("smtp.gmail.com", 465`)
if none of that work try to change your transfer security from `starttls()` to `SMTP_SSL`, so your code look like this:

```
import smtplib, ssl #import ssl module

port = 465  # For SSL

# Create a secure SSL context
context = ssl.create_default_context()

with smtplib.SMTP_SSL("smtp.gmail.com", port, context=context) as server:
    server.login(my_email, password)
    server.sendmail(from_addr=my_email, to_addrs=reciver_email, msg=message)
```